# Exclude fields from JSON serialization in Play Framework

Tags: json, serialization, playframework-2.3

When I send a model with my API developed with Play Framework 2.3, I serialize it like this :

```
public static JsonNode serialize(Object o) {
    return Json.toJson(o);
}
```

The problem is that all the fields of my model are serialized which is not very convenient for security and performance. Two questions :

1. How to exclude some fields ?
2. My fields are private and I
   generate getters/setters with [Lombok](http://projectlombok.org/). How can I modify the JSON
   serializer to use fluent getters/setters instead of
   `getMyField()/setMyField()` ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

`@JsonIgnore` and/or `@JsonProperty` annotations are what you need. More details [here](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-annotations/wiki/Jackson-Annotations).

Comment: Thanks for that. The problem is that these annotations are too static because what I want to handle is requests like this `GET /clients/007?fields=firstname,name`

Answer (score 0):

You can excludes the fields using filters,

Please see the link : http://www.baeldung.com/jackson-ignore-properties-on-serialization

Comment: Interesting ! So if I understand, I can instantiate my filter in my controller before serialization and exclude fields that are not requested by the caller of the API ?